# Extend JWT Time to live

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Laravel 5.5
Jwt Tymon Package
php 7.1

What i was wondering is it possible to extend the ttl of a token without refreshing it. I want to add time to existing token in the midlewhere. I do manage to change the values but the ttl on this token remains the same.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $claims = JWTAuth::getPayLoad()->toArray();
    $claims['exp'] = strtotime('+1 day', $claims['exp']);
    $payload = JWTFactory::make($claims);

    $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
    $response->headers->set('token',$token);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: It would work, but the client would need to implement storing it again.. you do know that your incrementing 1+day on exp on every request right?

Comment: yes i am aware of that, but i dont want it to be stored again, thats why i asked is it possible to extend the time and not change the token it self

Comment: No as its signed... Its just base64 url encoded json, but is signed so any change in the data, the token will not match, so you cant simply change something. It needs to be re-issued and stored.

Comment: So i am better off with just a basic refresh token logic?

Comment: You could look at exp and reissue it when a valid token is close to expiring or use a larger ttl.